# Calculate the number of tags, cnosdb process panic

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

I calculated the number of tags according to the instructions in [the official documentation](https://beta.docs.cnosdb.com/docs/reference/sql#count)：

the doc as follow:

```
COUNT(tag) 等价于 COUNT(DISTINCT tag)。
```

and I write the sql, as follow:

```
select count(station) from air;
+--------------------+
| COUNT(air.station) |
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
Query took 0.080 seconds.
```

I check the log, as follow:

```
isk_free":37466079232,"time":1706511114,"status":"Healthy"}
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  not yet implemented: collect count for tag
Location: tskv/src/reader/iterator.rs:1599

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 9 frames hidden ⋮                               
  10: tskv::reader::iterator::SeriesGroupRowIterator::fetch_next_row::{{closure}}::hef99f878137cbfc0
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  11: tskv::reader::iterator::RowIterator::new_series_group_iteration::{{closure}}::hb8742f89295be3d1
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::h3a36989687412b42
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::Context::run_task::h89ac4966b1809c22
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::run::hef38466e64340fcb
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  15: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::h8ed3a04cf6e9d542
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  16: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h79e3f2657106bb92
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  17: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::hfb5614ebaaf994b9
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  18: std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h8bc41380ef05be63
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  19: __pthread_joiner_wake<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>

Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
```

The method of calculating the number of tags has been introduced in the document. Why does it prompt that it is not implemented? my cnosdb version is :cnosdb 2.3.4, revision eca1b2434ffac536ac52b144ebbd280eace1122b